# Predictive mode, Auctex not playing nicely

Tags: latex, auctex, predictive-mode

I have predictive, auctex installed. I want predictive mode to work with my .tex files but I keep getting a warning of:

`Warning (emacs): Predictive major-mode setup function predictive-setup-latex failed; latex-mode support disabled`

after trying to turn on predictive mode with `M-x predictive-mode` when a `.tex` file is open.

I've found this issue here,

https://superuser.com/questions/326431/why-is-emacs-predictive-mode-not-working-for-latex-documents

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26109/emacs-predictive-mode-does-not-work-for-latex-documents

But both are inconclusive to me as I know predictive mode has successfully installed, its being managed by el-get.

Usually I debug with emacs --debug-init, but this is happening long after the .emacs is loaded.

Comment: Maybe `(debug-on-entry 'predictive-setup-latex)` might help

Comment: While that doesn't directly help me, thank you for providing that tip, didn't know about debug on entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging some more, I found the solution. Thank you Vamsi for the debug-on-entry tip.

I was getting the error because the predictive/latex wasn't on the load path. I assumed that el-get would take care of all the proper loading but it doesn't since predictive/latex, predictive/texinfo aren't really needed for all predictive use-cases. So the solution is to simply add them to the load-path.

The easiest and kludgiest solution is to add to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/predictive/latex")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/predictive/texinfo")
```

This answer of course assumes you are using `el-get` like I am.

Comment: I've added a [pull request](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/pull/2013/files) to fix this issue for el-get.